# EC2 reinstall ubuntu on amazon web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, instance

I have a ubuntu instance on AWS and I has installed some packages, and they make some errors.

Now I want clear everything and reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: In my case I need to stick with the same instance, so I create a new instance and then did a snapshot and load the new snapshot to instance that I want to restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easier to provision a new instance than re-use the same. If you have to stick with the instance then try removing/purging the packages you have installed. You can also run autoremove post removal of your packages to cleanup unwanted dependency which might have got installed.

Comment: I agree.  Better to replace the instance than try to debug it.  VMs are disposable.  Spend a few minutes on the current VM figuring out what went wrong and then spin up a new one while learning from the previous install.

Comment: what if you have data within the instance?? then what happens??